# Worksheet_change event handler changes a cell; how to stop it triggering itself?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I make the below the code work?  The problem is that when the event handler changes either of the values on the sheet, it is then triggered again.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dd As String
dd=0

If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
If Target.Name Like "*.colName" Then           
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("CN\" & dd & "\CNA.").RefersToRange.Value =  Range("CNS").Value
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("CN\" & dd & "\CNJ.").RefersToRange.Value =  Format(Now(),"MM/DD/YYYY")
End If

End Sub
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `Worksheet_Change` event handler that itself changes values on the worksheet then it will trigger the worksheet change event again at that step, running the event handler again, and ending up in a loop of recursive calls.  This is generally not what you want to happen!

To avoid this, set `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` at the start of the event handler.  This prevents your code from triggering any other events:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  'Your code here

  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that you need to set `EnableEvents` back to `True` at the end of the event handler, and it's also good practice to do this in an error handler so that it is set to true even if the sub fails for any reason.