# Method 'Formula' of object 'Range' failed on Worksheet Change Event - Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba, events, worksheet

what am i trying to accomplish:

I have a column of cells that have a formula (P5:P100), but i also want to be able to manually insert a value in those cells. Im trying to do this modifying Worksheet Change Event for the sheet. The code is as follows:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo Done

    If Application.Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("P5:P100")) Is Nothing Then GoTo Done


        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        ActiveCell.formula = _
        "=IF(N5=""+"",XLOOKUP(LEFT(O5,9),Table6[SKU],Table6[Costo Unitario (DOP)],""Revisar"",-1,-1),"""")"

        End If

Done:
End Sub
```

I get the " Method 'Formula' of object 'Range' failed" error on the formula line. I tried using a simpler formula and it doesnt give me the error.

Comment: If you `debug.print` that formula and copy it into a cell on that worksheet, does it give you an error? Also, I'd remove the `GoTo` statements as they are not best practice.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use this method. If someone updates a cell anywhere on the workbook and clicks 'Enter', if the below cell is empty it will get filled with this formula as long as `P5:P100` are empty.

Answer (score 1):

firstly I agree with data_sc that you may want to use this with caution.

Fixing the issue though:

I ran this through a few times and this is actually a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904616/worksheet-change-event-handler-changes-a-cell-how-to-stop-it-triggering-itself) though its not obvious why at first glance!

when your code runs it changes a cell actually triggering itself again i.e.

*user updates the cell -> code runs -> code updates a cell -> code runs*

On the second run your code then evaluates:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ""
```

however because of the if statement placed in the first run of the code (the one you actually wanted) if n5 is not + then the value of the if statement is ""

if you change to

```
If ActiveCell.Formula = ""
```

then your code will run and not error

a more full solution, removing the goto behaviour and using the solution at the link (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819244/vba-for-excel-how-to-check-intersection-of-ranges-are-not-empty) for intersect) would be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    If Target.Cells.Count < 2 And _
    Not Application.Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("P5:P100")) Is Nothing And _
    ActiveCell.Formula = "" Then
              ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(N5=""+"",2,"""")"
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

hope it helps

Comment: It worked great. Thanks a lot. This is my new code:

Answer (score 0):

It worked great. This is how the final code looks:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    If Target.Cells.Count < 2 And _
    Not Application.Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("P5:P100")) Is Nothing And _
    Target.formula = "" Then
              Target.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]=""+"",XLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-1],9),Table6[SKU],Table6[Costo Unitario (DOP)],""Revisar"",-1,-1),"""")"
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```